# Converting to Roman numerals

Tags: haskell, roman-numerals

As an excercise to "[Haskell: The Craft of Functional Programming](http://www.haskellcraft.com/craft3e/Home.html)", I created some code to convert an Integer to Roman numerals.

This is the first version and I think I'm probably not doing it in the "Haskell way" since my background is in imperative programming.

Any advice on how to improve this? Sometimes I think I'm missing a obvious way to do it in just one function.

```
convMap = [(1000,"M"), (900,"CM"), (500,"D"), (400,"CD"), (100,"C"),
           (90,"XC"), (50,"L"), (40,"XL"), (10,"X"), (9,"IX"), (5,"V"),
           (4,"IV"), (1,"I")]

toRoman :: Integer -> String
toRoman x 
  | x == 0 = "N"
  | otherwise = (snd . numToSubtract $ x) ++ toRoman'(nextNum)
      where nextNum = x - (fst. numToSubtract $ x)

-- Auxiliary function just so we treat 0 differently
-- (avoids 3 == "IIIN" if not used)
toRoman' :: Integer -> String
toRoman' x 
  | x == 0 = ""
  | x > 0 = (snd . numToSubtract $ x) ++ toRoman'(nextNum)
      where nextNum = x - (fst. numToSubtract $ x)

-- Returns which item in the convMap should be subtracted
numToSubtract :: Integer -> (Integer, String)
numToSubtract x = head (filter (lessThan x) convMap)

-- Filter function to work on the tuples in convMap
lessThan :: Integer -> (Integer, String) -> Bool
lessThan n (a, b)
  | a <= n = True
  | otherwise = False
```

Comment: Do you know about [hlint](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/)?

Comment: @MatrixFrog didn't know it until now! just installed and it's giving me tons of hints where to improve the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

**Booleans are normal values:**

```
lessThan n (a, b)
  | a <= n = True
  | otherwise = False
```

Simply write:

```
lessThan n (a, _) = a <= n
```

**Use pattern matching:**

```
toRoman' :: Integer -> String
toRoman' x 
  | x == 0 = ""
  | x > 0 = (snd . numToSubtract $ x) ++ toRoman'(nextNum)
      where nextNum = x - (fst. numToSubtract $ x)
```

If you want to take `fst` and `snd` of the same tuple, think about pattern matching.
Minor point: brackets in `toRoman'(nextNum)` are redundant, simply write `toRoman' nextNum`.

```
toRoman' :: Integer -> String
toRoman' x
  | x == 0 = ""
  | x > 0 = b ++ toRoman' (x - a)
      where (a, b) = numToSubtract x
```

**Remove duplication:**

`toRoman` and `toRoman'` contain duplicate code. In fact `toRoman` is only used to treat specially 0, so can be changed:

```
toRoman :: Integer -> String
toRoman 0 = "N"
toRoman x = toRoman' x
```

**Move or remove utility functions:**

`lessThan` and `numToSubtract` are used only once and don't seem to be generally useful, maybe inline them:

```
toRoman' :: Integer -> String
toRoman' x
  | x == 0 = ""
  | x > 0 = b ++ toRoman' (x - a)
      where (a, b) = head $ filter (\(a,_) -> a <= x) convMap
```

As Dan Burton commented, you can write also:

```
      where (a, b) = head $ filter ((<= x) . fst) convMap
```

**Final code**

```
convMap = [(1000,"M"), (900,"CM"), (500,"D"), (400,"CD"), (100,"C"),
           (90,"XC"), (50,"L"), (40,"XL"), (10,"X"), (9,"IX"), (5,"V"),
           (4,"IV"), (1,"I")]

-- Auxiliary function just so we treat 0 differently
-- (avoids 3 == "IIIN" if not used)
toRoman :: Integer -> String
toRoman 0 = "N"
toRoman x = toRoman' x

toRoman' :: Integer -> String
toRoman' x 
  | x == 0 = ""
  | x > 0 = b ++ toRoman' (x - a)
      where (a, b) = head $ filter ((<= x) . fst) convMap
```

**Fold**

If you stare a little at the code, it turns out you *each entry from `convMap` only once*. First you check how many M's you need. Then CM's. Then D's. And so on. Using "filter" function always restarts search from beginning. In fact, toRoman can be written as a fold!

```
import Data.List (genericReplicate)

convMap = [(1000,"M"), (900,"CM"), (500,"D"), (400,"CD"), (100,"C"),
           (90,"XC"), (50,"L"), (40,"XL"), (10,"X"), (9,"IX"), (5,"V"),
           (4,"IV"), (1,"I")]

toRoman :: Integer -> String
toRoman 0 = "N"
toRoman x | x > 0 = snd $ foldl f (x,[]) convMap
  where f (n,s) (rn, rs) = (l, s ++ concat (genericReplicate k rs))
              where (k,l) = divMod n rn
```

**Going crazy with abstractions**

Erik Hilton's nice answer gives a solution using `unfoldr`. So you can write the code using fold and unfold, and these are two ways of looking at it. I believe that combination of fold and unfold is called "paramorphism" or "apomorphism" or something like that...

Comment: I would write that lambda like this: `((<= x) . fst)`. Also, it might make more sense semantically to use `dropwhile ((> x) . fst)` instead of `filter`; or even use `find` instead. However, in either case, the actual list traversal is identical.

Comment: I referenced this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49584216/633183) :D

Answer (score 11):

Try something like this

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

convMap = [(1000,"M"), (900,"CM"), (500,"D"), (400,"CD"), (100,"C"),
           (90,"XC"), (50,"L"), (40,"XL"), (10,"X"), (9,"IX"), (5,"V"),
           (4,"IV"), (1,"I")]

intToRoman :: Int -> String
intToRoman = concat . unfoldr findLeast
             where findLeast n = case i of 
                                 Just (x,r) -> Just(r,n-x)
                                 Nothing -> Nothing
                                 where i = find (\(val,_) -> val <= n) convMap
```

Unfoldr is a function that is sadly underused but exactly what you want here. It takes a seed value, the one you are trying to convert and builds up a list (of roman numeral parts). This might be a touch more verbose than absolutely necessary but I believe it is very clear.

A note on how unfoldr works: you pass it a seed value and a function. this function returns either `Just(a,b)` or `Nothing`. In the former case, a is added to the accumulator and b is used as the next seed value. This will continue until the function returns `Nothing`. At this point the unfoldr is complete.

Comment: You can write `intToRoman = concat . unfoldr findLeast`

Comment: Ahh yes! Superb. Changing now. I always forget the point-free way.

Comment: thank you very much. I'll be studying the Data.* modules.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my take on it. I've changed the algorithm slightly so that it only has to traverse `convMap` once.

```
toRoman 0 = "N"
toRoman x | x < 0 = error "toRoman: negative number"
toRoman x = loop x convMap
  where loop 0 _ = ""
        loop x cs@((a, b):cs') | x >= a    = b ++ loop (x - a) cs
                               | otherwise = loop x cs'
```

The pattern is perhaps a little ugly, but other than that I think it's both readable and efficient. You could also write it as a fold,

```
toRoman x = snd $ foldl f (x, []) convMap
  where f (x, s) (a, b) = let (q, r) = quotRem x a in (r, s ++ concat (replicate q b))
```

but that's slightly less efficient due to quadratic appending. Difference lists would work, but that would only make it messier.

Comment: Nice! What does cs@((a, b):cs' mean? I know what (cs:cs') means - first item and rest of the list. I have never seen it written like that before :)

Comment: Guessing I think that cs would be the whole list and cs' is the whole list minus the first 2 elements while a and b being those elements. Was that correct?

Comment: @Ancide: Almost. `(a, b)` is a tuple, so the whole pattern matches a list of tuples, where `a` and `b` are the components of the first tuple, `cs'` is the remaining tuples, and `cs` is the entire list. To match the first and second element of a list, you'd use the `:` pattern twice: `a:b:cs'`.

Comment: @hammer I keep getting amazed all the time of how awesome Haskell is! Thank you for explaining! :)